# Why can't I just dd the Windows 10 ISO to an USB stick?

Tags: windows, boot, unetbootin

Why can't I just use isohybrid and then dd the Windows 10 ISO to a USB stick and boot it, and call it a day?

What is so special about this ISO?

Most posts refer to either using a Windows machine to create the bootable USB device, or try using Unetbootin. But even using Unetbootin, requires a very ugly solution of modifying the file system manually while the tool is running, setting the bootable flag manually, etc.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162174/how-do-i-use-unetbootin-to-make-a-bootable-windows-usb-installer

Is this for real? Why is it so hard to make a bootable Windows USB stick?

Comment: Good question. I'd posit its because the media layout for metadata between optical disks and USB disks is different. if the iso contained a USB-compatible image, then dd would work fine, but since the image is formatted for optical layout, it won't work without a translation/relocation of the media and image metadata.

Comment: [This guide](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/) attempts to create a Windows 10 ISO in Ubuntu.

Comment: See [this detailed answer](https://superuser.com/a/1527373/53547) by the developer of Rufus.