# How to burn a distro iso on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, iso-image, usb-flash-drive

I use Windows 10 home and I consider to migrate to Ubuntu.

I took an empty disk-on-key (DoK) and putted inside it a Ubuntu 22.04 iso file.

My Dell Latitude 5580 laptop is "modern" in the sense that I can't choose how to boot in bios, i.e. booting should be done automatically if a DoK contains an iso which is burnt.

How to burn a distro iso on Windows?

Perhaps this question is a better fit for a website about software recommendations because I might need some third party software to do that or some Windows non-[WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) software.

Comment: Balena Etcher or Rufus are very popular choices. The Ubuntu downloads page has instructions.

Comment: As someone who is used to the good old way of just putting the iso in a DoK, this is a culture shock.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what "good old way"?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski what I know as the good old way is to just put in iso in a DOK and boot from there, without "burning". I have installed an OS years before, maybe I misrecall and it was by CD and not by USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just copy an .iso file to a USB drive and boot off of it.  You need a program like [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) or [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to properly "burn" the ISO to the USB disk.

Comment: Actually if you want UEFI only, you can manually format an external drive with a large FAT32 partition with esp,boot flags, and then extract ISO into the FAT32 partition. It will not work with some types of ISO where any file is over 4GB (Windows). But does work with Ubuntu.

Comment: @oldfred Seems right. Some insight from Rufus developer: [here](https://superuser.com/a/1527373/432690).