# Live Kali ISO - 3 files with exact same name

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, iso-image

I downloaded Live kali ISO which contains all packages. It's ISO is about 10.3GB. It boots properly in VM.

https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-live    Everything ISO file

When I opened the ISO using PowerISO, I find that there are 3 files named `filesystem.squashfs` inside the same .\live folder.

How is this possible? While it seems to be the Linux compressed filesystem, and looks like a split file but how come files names are exactly the same? As a result I can not extract the ISO, directly it warns about file overwriting from PowerISO.

When I mount it in Windows 10, all filesystem.squashfs become a single 10GB file by same name.
Can someone explain this? 3 files with same name inside same folder in ISO file.
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Wikipedia [ISO 9660 article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660#Directories_and_files):

> As the length of a file's extent on disc is stored in a 32 bit value, it allows for a maximum length of just over 4.2 GB (more precisely, one byte less than 4 GiB). It is possible to circumvent this limitation by using the multi-extent (fragmentation) feature of ISO 9660 Level 3 to create ISO 9660 file systems and single files up to 8 TB. With this, files larger than 4 GiB can be split up into multiple extents (sequential series of sectors), each not exceeding the 4 GiB limit.

Apparently your PowerISO does not support this.

Side note: the file in question uses a [major hack called *isohybrid*](https://superuser.com/a/1527373/432690). In Linux `file -k kali-linux-2022.2-live-everything-amd64.iso` reports both `ISO 9660 …` and `DOS/MBR boot sector; …`. The hack does not revoke limitations of ISO 9660.