# How to burn an ISO file into a disk-on-key in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, iso-image, windows-11, imgburn

I use Ubuntu 22.04.

I have downloaded a Windows 11 `iso` file.

How to burn an ISO file into USB disk-on-key in Ubuntu?

Comment: What's a "DoK"?

Comment: [Not with `dd`](https://superuser.com/q/1527197/432690).

Comment: @gronostaj disk on key, I have edited.

Comment: One possibility: https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy

Comment: Hello @Robert I am not a native application programmer and never compiled native application code. Is compiling needed there?

Comment: @gumarabic No. Ventoy is in my experience the most reliable tool that can get this to work under Linux

Comment: @Robert If you could post that as an answer with an explanation how to use it, it would get my upvote

Comment: Sorry I don't have any experience on that tool I just know that it exists.

Comment: @gronostaj sadly I don't know how to run it in Linux (Ubuntu), there is no `apt install` or anything similar that I've found in a quick look in the Ventoy docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ventoy. Once set up, it's remarkably easy to use.

Links to downloads of the latest release can be found [here](https://www.ventoy.net/en/download.html). When I'm typing this, the latest version is 1.0.78, with the Linux version available [here](https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy/releases/download/v1.0.78/ventoy-1.0.78-linux.tar.gz).

Download it and unpack to any directory. Next you have to run `VentoyWeb.sh` as root. Right-click empty space in the extracted directory, select *Open in Terminal*, then in the window that opens type `sudo ./VentoyWeb.sh`. Then open the link that appears (http://127.0.0.1:24680) in your browser. In the *Option* menu check *Secure boot support*. If you want to install in UEFI mode, change *Partition Style* to *GPT*. Select the USB device and press *Install*. **Warning: this will erase everything from the flash drive.**

Ventoy is now installed and a new drive called *Ventoy* should appear in the file explorer. Now simply copy the ISO file to that drive. It works with Windows and dozens of Linux flavors.

After booting from the flash drive, a Ventoy boot menu will appear with one item for each ISO you've copied. Select the one you're interested in booting (Windows) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.