# Windows 11 iso from microsoft.com is recognized as unbootable

Tags: iso-image, windows-11

I went **[here](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11)** to download a ***Windows 11 Disk Image (ISO)***.

After downloading this image I tried to burn it into a disk-on-key with [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), but I got the following error:

> It looks like this is not a bootable image. The image does not appear to contain a partition table, and might not be recognized or bootable by your device

How could this be explained?

It should be noted that Balena Etcher allows me to **continue** but I chose not to. I first need to know what I did wrong if at all.

Comment: Your ISO is probably corrupt.  Why not use the [windows media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) instead to create your USB stick.  It will CRC check the ISO when it is downloaded.

Comment: The ISO is probably fine. It's just not a "hybrid" ISO, because none of Microsoft ISOs are. They need special treatment. It's actually a creative hack that makes most Linux ISOs bootable after writing to a USB drive. Assumption that any ISO would work that way is incorrect.

Comment: @gronostaj I don't know what to do then? Shall I continue anyway? and by the way, I can also burn such ISO from Ubuntu 22.04 with Ventoy, I replied about this in my other post where you also commented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to burn an ISO file into a disk-on-key in Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1731023/how-to-burn-an-iso-file-into-a-disk-on-key-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @gumarabic - You can either use Rufus which I know will work with Microsoft ISOs or use the Media Creation Tool.

Comment: In the case of UEFI booting, all you need to do is pretty much just mount it and copy the files inside to an NTFS-formatted drive. (In reality, most if not all UEFI firmware on the market have NTFS driver.)

Comment: @TomYan The _only_ UEFIs with NTFS support that I'm aware of are those in Intel's NUC computers. Most systems, in my experience, supports the minimum that the specs requires, ie. the FAT family. Microsoft's tools and Rufus create a tiny FAT32 partition with UEFI NTFS driver on it to work around this. If you know about other systems with NTFS support built into UEFI, I'd be happy to know what those are.

Comment: @gronostaj My bad. Apparently it's an AMI (Aptio) thing to have NTFS DXE. I have a both an 11th-gen intel laptop and an 4th-gen intel desktop (ASUS motherboard), both have Aptio and I'm 100% certain they can boot directly from NTFS. You can e.g. inspect [the CAP](https://www.asus.com/us/SupportOnly/H87-PRO/HelpDesk_BIOS/) of the latter with UEFITool (by searching `NTFS` under `Text`) if interested. AFAICT Intel NUCs do have Aptio as well. But I also just checked samples of Phoenix and Insyde, turns out they indeed do NOT have NTFS DXE (probably because I've been chainloading with `grub`...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for some reason Balena Etcher shows this error message when trying to install Windows. I have no explanation as to why. However, following is a possible solution:

On Ubuntu, you could use [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_start.html).

1. Download, extract and cd
2. `sudo ./VentoyWeb.sh`
3. Open link in browser and press install (it installs Ventoy on your UBS)
4. Copy Windows11.iso to the mount named "ventoy"
5. Reboot from usb

Here's a walkthrough on how to use it [Ventoy Tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/use-ventoy/). In the boot menu, use  "wimboot"

(Let me save you some time if you thought about ignoring this warning. It doesn't work)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1237049)